# How to filter out NaN in javascripts Filter function

Tags: javascript, function, filter

I need helping filtering out `NaN`

```
var trimmer =[7, "ate", "", false, 9];

var filt = value=> value !==false && value!==''&& value!==undefined&&  
value!==null&&  value!==NaN;


trimmer.filter(filt);

//works for this->[7, "ate", "", false, 9];
//but not for [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
//need help filtering out NaN
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Comment: I'm trying to return  , for =>  ```[7, "ate",' ', false, 9];```  return ```[7, "ate", 9];``` removing false and the empty string and for =>  ```[false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]``` return  ```[ ]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript treats 0 as false, so its get filtered. Need to check type of variable , if it is number return true.

```js
var trimmer = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];

console.log(trimmer.filter(e=>e));
```

Comment: I dont want the zero returned ,i want this => ```[ ]``` instead i get this => ```[NaN]```

Comment: Then @Jonas's solution is perfect for you

Comment: so i did this ```var filt = value=> value !==false && value!==''&& value!==undefined&&  value!==null &&isNaN(value)!=true && value!=0;``` and it ate my string in ```[7, "ate", "", false, 9]``` :)

Comment: I tried @jonas solution and  and weirdly it works flawlessly (almost) but it doesn't remove the empty string ```''```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `isNan()` function instead. Follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to see more example.

Answer (score 2):

NaN is falsy ( false,undefined,null,"",0 are too):

```
trimmer.filter(e=>e);
```

Comment: I don't have a problem removing the empy string that works just fine here => ```&& value!==''```

Comment: @rhodoscoder then the upper one would he the best solution

Comment: Tried it and weirdly it works flawlessly (almost) but it doesn't remove the empty string ```''```

Comment: @rhodosCoder it does. If it is really empty. " " <= not empty

Comment: @rhodos code youre welcome ;) then feel free to hit the green checkmark ;)

Answer (score 1):

NaN == NaN will always gives you false.

```js
var trimmer =[false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
var trimmer1 =[7, "ate", "", false, 9];

var filt = value=> value !==false && value!==''&& value!==undefined&&  
value!==null && value.toString() !== "NaN" && value !== 0;


console.log(trimmer.filter(filt));
console.log(trimmer1.filter(filt));
//works for this->[7, "ate", "", false, 9];
//but not for [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];
//need help filtering out NaN
```

Comment: I'm trying to return  , for =>  ```[7, "ate",' ', false, 9];```  return ```[7, "ate", 9];``` removing false and the empty string and for =>  ```[false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]``` return  ```[ ]```

Comment: i updated my answer please check now. is that you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Rohodos simple change value `!= NaN` to `!isNAN(value)`

so your code now look like

`var trimmer = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];`

`var filt = value=> value !==false && value!==''&& value!==undefined&&value!==null&&  !isNaN(value);`

`trimmer.filter(filt);`

Comment: ```var trimmer = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""];

    var filt = value=> value !==false && value!==''&& value!==undefined&&  
    value!==null &&isNaN(value)==true;
 

    trimmer.filter(filt);``` .How does NaN still not filter out after this

Comment: Rohodos `isNaN(value)==true;`  it should be `isNaN(value)==false; ` becuase we are filtiring out the NaN value ,not including it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out specifically NaN but leave behind other falsey values then this will work:

```
const trimmerWithoutNaN = trimmer.filter(val => !isNaN(val))
```